# FlushConsoleInputBuffer() isn't flushing the input buffer

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-console

I am trying to use the WinAPI function `FlushConsoleInputBuffer`, but I either don't completely understand how to use it, or how it works. 
I am using it to flush the standard input buffer in a console app.
The only thing I am trying to do is flush the buffer so program execution will stop at the `getline` statement. The purpose is to find a way other than using `cin.ignore` and to use a WinAPI function.

Your insight is appreciated.

```
HANDLE hStdOut, hStdIn;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO cScrnBuffInfoOut;

    bool bIsConsoleFlushed = FALSE;
    bool bConsoleInputBufferInfo = FALSE;
    char buff[80] = {0};
    string response;

    //-- get handle to the standard input and standard output
    hStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    bConsoleInputBufferInfo = GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &cScrnBuffInfoOut);

    cout << "Enter string 1\n";
    bIsConsoleFlushed = FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hStdIn);
    scanf("%s", buff);

    cout << "Enter string 2\n";
 // cin.ignore(); 
    bIsConsoleFlushed = FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hStdIn);  
    getline(cin, response);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely, the problem lies into mixing `cin`/`cout` calls, with WINAPI ones. If you want to perform manipulations on `cin`, do that, with methods that it provides you. If you want to use WINAPI for input/output, use that. Typically bad things happen when you try to mix APIs like that (due to differing inner-workings).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius.
Thank you, I guess I was thinking that the standard input buffer was the same that the `winapi` used. So would you say that this function should be used with a `winapi` function like `ReadConsole()` and then it would work?

Comment: I can't say if it will work, since I don't remember if I ever used WINAPI functions for console manipulation. But I won't stop you from trying.

Comment: Flushing the console's input buffer has no effect on what's already read and buffered in the `stdin` stream. C `FILE` streams have their own buffers implemented on top of OS buffering and caching.

Comment: To answer your question in the above comment, you can use either `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole` to read directly from the console. Typically the console is in cooked mode (echo input, line input, and processed input). In this case, `ReadFile` supports Ctrl+Z to indicate EOF (i.e. 0 bytes read) when a line begins with Ctrl+Z. `ReadConsole` doesn't implement this feature, but anyway you should use `ReadConsoleW` (note the "W" suffix) for Unicode support. NT-only console applications such as cmd.exe have used `ReadConsoleW` since the first release of Windows NT in 1993.